# Specifying the Return Error Code on Application Exit

Tags: c#, exit-code

How can the return error code be specified on application exit?  If this were a VC++ application, I could use the `SetLastError(ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)` -- `return GetLastError()` APIs.  Is there a way to do this in C#?

```
  static int Main(string[] args)
  {
     Tool.Args = args;

     Application.EnableVisualStyles();
     Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
     Application.Run(new Download_Tool());

     return Tool.ErrorCode;
  }
```

How can the `Tool.ErrorCode` value be set intelligably?  If I try something like `Tool.ErrorCode = ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`, I get an error, "The name ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED does not exist in the current context."  Thanks.

*ADDITIONAL INFORMATION*

My example is over-simplified.  Is there a way to something like this:

```
Tool.ErrorCode = ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED;
return Tool.ErrorCode;
```

...which generates a compile-error, rather than this:

```
Tool.ErrorCode = 5;
return Tool.ErrorCode;
```

...which works, but uses a "magic number."  I'd like to avoid the use of magic numbers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx

```
Environment.Exit(exitCode)
```

**Update**

The reason why you get a compile error with "ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED" is because you have not defined it. You need to define it yourself:

```
const int ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED = 5;
```

Then you can use:

```
Environment.Exit(ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
```

**Update 2**

If you are looking for a ready-made set of winerror.h constants for your C# needs, then here it is:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Constants/WINERROR.html

I would probably modify the GetErrorName(...) method to do some caching though, e.g.:

```
private static Dictionary<int, string> _FieldLookup;

public static bool TryGetErrorName(int result, out string errorName)
{
    if (_FieldLookup == null)
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> tmpLookup = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(ResultWin32).GetFields();

        foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
        {
            int errorCode = (int)field.GetValue(null);

            tmpLookup.Add(errorCode, field.Name);
        }

        _FieldLookup = tmpLookup;
    }

    return _FieldLookup.TryGetValue(result, out errorName);
}
```

Comment: This does not address the problem of using magic numbers to set the exit code.

Comment: I'd like to know why this was voted down. Hopefully it wasn't after the question was updated. I'm not a mind reader... That would be pretty poor.

Comment: Microsoft already has these error codes defined somewhere. In a VC++ application they can be accessed by `#include "Winerror.h"`. Is there not something similar for C#?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381(VS.85).aspx

Comment: @Jim To my knowledge no there is not. In the past when doing PInvoke I have simply taken header files and extracted the constants into a C# helper class to get the parity you are after. C# in *not* Win32.

Comment: @Jim I have updated the answer to include a link to C# code for a class that has all the winerror.h constants. HTH.

Comment: Why the downvote on 29/11/2010. Someone seems to have tracked through a whole bunch of my questions and down voted. Not nice.

Answer (score -1):

Set `Environment.ExitCode`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     Tool.Args = args;

     Application.EnableVisualStyles();
     Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
     Application.Run(new Download_Tool());

     Environment.ExitCode = Tool.ErrorCode;
  }
```

See [MSDN - Environment.ExitCode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exitcode.aspx)

Comment: This does not address the problem of using magic numbers to set the exit code.

Comment: The problem with this code snippet is that the value of  `Environment.ExitCode` is ignored if the `Main` method returns anything other than void (i.e. `int` in this case).

Comment: I changed the code snippet to return void, so that Environment.ExitCode will not be ignored.